# struts check if a form is present

Tags: struts

In a jsp file, to check if an attribute is present or not we can use

```
<nested:present property="myAttribute">
    //implement logic
</nested:present>
```

But how if we wanna check if a form is present or not?

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This can do the work:

```
<nested:present name="myForm">
    //implement logic
</nested:present>
```